# ArrayList of ArrayList showing unwanted result

Tags: java

```
//I want my to be something like this: [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2].....,[4,2],[4,3]]


public class Japan {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> nodeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            nodeList.add(i);
            nodeList.add(j);
            nodes.add(nodeList);
            nodeList.remove(1);
            nodeList.remove(0);
         }
    }
    System.out.println(nodes);
}}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to enter some code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you are re-using the same inner ArrayList - you add the inner ArrayList to the outer ArrayList several times, and everything you add to the inner ArrayList gets deleted, so when you print it, the inner list is empty.

`nodes.add(nodeList)` does *not* copy `nodeList` - it adds a reference to the same list.

You need to either create a copy when you call `nodes.add`:

```
public class Japan {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> nodeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            nodeList.add(i);
            nodeList.add(j);
            nodes.add(new ArrayList<>(nodeList)); // This copies nodeList, and adds the copy to nodes
            nodeList.remove(1);
            nodeList.remove(0);
         }
    }
    System.out.println(nodes);
}}
```

or create a new inner list each time through the loop:

```
public class Japan {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> nodeList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this creates a new list each time it is executed
            nodeList.add(i);
            nodeList.add(j);
            nodes.add(nodeList);
         }
    }
    System.out.println(nodes);
}}
```

Both of these will work, but I (and probably most programmers) find the second one easier to understand, so I would prefer that approach. (If you can't see *why* the second one is easier to understand, it will come to you in time)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you initialize a list for each of the `i` indexes,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    list.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
}
```

then do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        list.get(i).add(j);
    }
}
```